# How to install greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I am trying to install greenplum. I was trying to do it in ubuntu vm. But I am not getting proper links to install it. Can anyone help me in installing greenplum?

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum can be downloaded from here: https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gpdb
You cannot run it on Ubuntu, it is not in the list of supported databases. I'd recommend you to choose CentOS or OpenSUSE

Answer (score 0):

greenplum only provides install package for redhat/centos, but of course you can install it on ubuntu in many ways.

1. the easy way is to checkout this [link](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2012/10/06/installing-greenplum-community-edition-database-4-2-on-debian-wheezy/) to install greenplum on debian/ubuntu. it uses the official install package and does some hack.
2. the hard way is to build it from source and install. check out the guide on [github](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb). chances are that you are gonna required to install a lot of dependencies, but surely you will succeed.